# How to make application running in Virtual Box accessible over the public internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, portforwarding

I have a simple application running on my VirtualBox VM. I can access it on any computer on my network through it's network ip and the app's port number: `192.34.24.563:8080`.  I'd like to be able to access the app on the public internet though.  I know port-forwarding is needed, I'm just not able to find any docs on how to do this when your forwarding to a virtual machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your IP address is private it can only be accessed in your network.
You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get some URL to your application.
Share this URL with your friend anywhere.

If you are planning to make your application public then you can find some cloud solutions like Azure, AWS, GCP or Heroku.

You can deploy a small web application in [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/home) for free.